# Wordpress - unable plugin update ftp login

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress blog on a server, the admin portal is also on the same server.

The auto update of plugins from the admin portal is not working.
I get an error saying that I am not authorize to login.

```
Error message - Error: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.
```

I know the login details are correct.

Could the problem be that the server is trying to connect to itself ?

I have looked at the other articles about this problem, I havent got SELinex installed and the permissions seem to be correct.

Directories

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root     root       200 May 23  2010 .htaccess
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1406 May 16  2010 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   397 May 25  2008 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 15410 Dec  6  2008 license.txt
drwxr-xr-x  6 www-data www-data  4096 Jul 28  2010 mint
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  9122 Jul 22  2010 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  4391 Apr 19  2010 wp-activate.php
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  3 12:33 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 40284 Jul 25  2010 wp-app.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   220 Oct 14  2008 wp-atom.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   274 May 25  2008 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3926 May  6  2010 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   238 Oct 14  2008 wp-commentsrss2.php 
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3173 May 25  2010 wp-config-sample.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3208 Sep  5 14:49 wp-config.php
drwxrw-rw- 19 www-data www-data  4096 Feb  8 21:59 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  1255 Mar 17  2010 wp-cron.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   240 Apr 19  2010 wp-feed.php
drwxr-xr-x  7 www-data www-data  4096 Sep  3 12:41 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2002 Mar 18  2010 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  2441 Feb 28  2010 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 26059 Jun  1  2010 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  7774 May 26  2010 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   487 Apr 20  2009 wp-pass.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   218 Oct 14  2008 wp-rdf.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   316 May 25  2008 wp-register.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   218 Oct 14  2008 wp-rss.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data   220 Oct 14  2008 wp-rss2.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  9177 May  2  2010 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 18695 Jul 21  2010 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data  3702 Feb 24  2010 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 www-data www-data 94184 Jul 14  2010 xmlrpc.php
```

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Please show the exact error message you are getting and a redacted version of the login details would also be helpful

Comment: Error: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to give www-data permission in wordpress directory:

```
cd /yourwordpressdirectory/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data *
```